# Оформление кода css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Собственно вопрос, посоветуйте готовое решение для оформления примеров кода, например как тут или хабре, вот так:

Пример

```
jQuery(function($){
  alert('example') 
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Syntax+Highlighter

Comment: спасибо Вам Timur Musharapov

Answer (score 2):

Вот популярный плагин https://highlightjs.org/

Впрочем, подобных миллион - ключевые слова: highlight syntax